# Removing scientific notation from axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

Hi I need to remove the *10^4 from the axis and just make the points 10000,20000,30000 instead of 1*10^4, 2*10^4...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=10,
    ymin=0,ymax=30000,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    axis line style=-,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ytick={0,10000,20000,30000},
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style= dashed
    ]


    \addplot expression[domain=0:10]{(26000*e^(-0.2*x))+(3000*e^(-0.4*x))+1000};       


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `scaled ticks = false`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=10,
    ymin=0,ymax=30000,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    axis line style=-,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ytick={0,10000,20000,30000},
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style= dashed,
    scaled ticks = false, % <=== add this
    ]
    \addplot expression[domain=0:10]{(26000*e^(-0.2*x))+(3000*e^(-0.4*x))+1000};       


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, worked a charm